# GTA type effect [Photoshop]

Tags: photoshop, image-editing, photoshop-cs5

I'm new to `Photoshop` and was wondering how can I give my photo a `cartoon effect` just like in the **GTA** cover. I looked everywhere, youtube, blogs and stuff but still non were close to what I'm looking for. Look at the picture for clarity:

[image]

I tried the following but didn't get what I was looking for:

1. Made a `duplicate layer` of the `image` and then **Filter** -> **Sketch** -> **Stamp** and after that `multiply` them.
2. **Image** -> **Adjustment** -> **Posterize**
3. **Filer** -> **Sharpen** -> **Unsharp** **Mask**

Using **PS CS5 Extended**.

Is there any fast and better way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: **NOTE:** For answers to this question: [Click here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37853/how-to-get-gta-type-cartoon-effect-in-photoshop-cs5).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com may be a better suited platform for asking your question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for asking such question.

From what I can see on your picture, there's an ink-like effect like in Street Fighter 4, there is a [tutorial here](http://www.devwebpro.com/street-fighter-iv-style/) on how to do that.

Now regarding the shading, if the source was in 3D they probably used [Cel Shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading), find a tutorial [here](http://celesse.deviantart.com/art/Photoshop-Cel-Shading-Tutorial-9731752).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways of doing it:
1. 
Filter/Blur/Smart blur with Radius 3, Threshold 15, then
Filter/Filter Gallery / Artistic/Poster Edges with Thickness 8, Intensity 1, 
or
2. 
buy the effect action (3$) which does the above
http://graphicriver.net/item/grand-photoshop-action/11341606

Comment: Looks convincing. Thanks for the share. I'll look into it. :)

Answer (score 0):

First go Filter -> Filter gallery -> poster edges   increase thickness level to 5 or something that suits best for the image and intensity lesser than thickness value and Posterization value to mid level(3 or 4)

Then Filter -> Filter gallery -> cutout    increase levels,keep simplicity to 0 and fidelity to 0 or 1